# SMTP Error: Could not authenticate

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, email, smtp

In wordpress I am getting error SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

Here is the log file:

```
Versions:
WordPress: 5.6
WordPress MS: No
PHP: 7.4.3
WP Mail SMTP: 2.5.1

Params:
Mailer: smtp
Constants: Yes
ErrorInfo: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
Host: mail.vitalticks.com
Port: 587
SMTPSecure: tls
SMTPAutoTLS: bool(true)
SMTPAuth: bool(true)

Server:
OpenSSL: OpenSSL 1.1.1f 31 Mar 2020
Apache.mod_security: No

Debug:
Mailer: Other SMTP
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

SMTP Debug:
2021-01-05 05:42:43 Connection: opening to mail.vitalticks.com:587, timeout=300, options=array()

2021-01-05 05:42:43 Connection: opened

2021-01-05 05:42:44 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-server.vitalticks.com ESMTP Exim 4.93 #2 Mon, 04 Jan 2021 22:42:44 -0700 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.

2021-01-05 05:42:44 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO jasdental.in

2021-01-05 05:42:44 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-server.vitalticks.com Hello ec2-3-6-131-50.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com [3.6.131.50]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-STARTTLS250 HELP

2021-01-05 05:42:44 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS

2021-01-05 05:42:44 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead

2021-01-05 05:42:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO jasdental.in

2021-01-05 05:42:45 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-server.vitalticks.com Hello ec2-3-6-131-50.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com [3.6.131.50]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250 HELP

2021-01-05 05:42:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN

2021-01-05 05:42:45 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6

2021-01-05 05:42:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]

2021-01-05 05:42:46 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6

2021-01-05 05:42:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]

2021-01-05 05:42:48 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 Incorrect authentication data

2021-01-05 05:42:48 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 Incorrect authentication data

SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

2021-01-05 05:42:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT

2021-01-05 05:42:48 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 server.vitalticks.com closing connection

2021-01-05 05:42:48 Connection: closed

SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

Answer (score 1):

our team had enabled two factor authentication for mail so for this reason i am getting error.
after disabling the two factor authentication SMTP is working.

Comment: That's the wrong solution. Your 2FA system should be able to generate an application password for you to use here instead, so you can re-enable 2FA in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

```
Password command failed: 535 Incorrect authentication data
```

The password is wrong.

Comment: password is not wrong because i am able to access my mail account thorugh the same password.

Comment: Well, that might be true, but that is what the error message tells you - I can't confirm either as I don't know.

Comment: Search other SO tickets, this might be a server configuration error - https://stackoverflow.com/a/14445642/591486

Comment: i am using AWS not cpanel.

Comment: Ok - did you search for information about this error relating to AWS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47128467/aws-ses-with-phpmailer-using-smtp-smtp-error-could-not-authenticate